# C-Socket Programming-"undefined reference"

Tags: c, sockets, tcpclient, undefined-reference, dev-c++

I am a beginner in socket programming in C. I got the code in the book and when I compiled, these are following error with undefined reference. Please give a tips to correct this!Thank you!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define RCVBUFSIZE 32
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr;
unsigned short echoServPort;
char *servIP;
char *echoString;
char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
unsigned int echoStringLen;
int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd;
if(argc>3 || argc>4){
    printf("Usage: %s <Server IP> <Echo Word> [<Echo Port>\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
servIP=argv[1];
echoString=argv[2];
if(argc==4){
    echoServPort=atoi(argv[3]);
}
else{
    echoServPort=7;
}
if((sock=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))<0){
    printf("socket() failed!");
}
memset(&echoServAddr,0,sizeof(echoServAddr));
echoServAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(servIP);
echoServAddr.sin_port=htons(echoServPort);
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0){
    printf("connect() failed!");
}
echoStringLen=strlen(echoString);
if(send(sock,echoString, echoStringLen,0)!=echoStringLen){
    printf("send() send maximum bytes than expected");
}
totalBytesRcvd=0;
printf("Received");
while(totalBytesRcvd<echoStringLen){
    if((bytesRcvd=recv(sock,echoBuffer,RCVBUFSIZE-1,0))<=0){
        printf("recv() failed!");
    }
    totalBytesRcvd+=bytesRcvd;
    echoBuffer[bytesRcvd]='\0';
    printf(echoBuffer);
}
close(sock);
exit(1);    
}
```

I got errors as follow:

```
In function `main':
        client.cpp:34: undefined reference to `_socket@12'
        client.cpp:39: undefined reference to `_inet_addr@4'
        client.cpp:40: undefined reference to `_htons@4'
        client.cpp:41: undefined reference to `_connect@12'
        client.cpp:45: undefined reference to `_send@16'
        client.cpp:51: undefined reference to `_recv@16'
        collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You forgot to link with the Ws2_32.lib library

Comment: How to link with the Ws2_32.lib library ? I use Dev C++ IDE.

Comment: Look at the dev-c++ documentation.

Comment: @Nguyen Tan Dat, I had edited my answer with guide on how to use ws2_32.lib into your Dev C++ IDE :)

Answer (score 6):

From my observation, you're trying to build Winsock application with MinGW.

MinGW, by default, don't link Winsock library (which is ***Ws2_32.lib***) automatically, so you need to manually tell compiler by using **-l** flag plus name of your library.

```
gcc winsock.c -o winsock.exe -lws2_32
```

Edit : If you're IDE which are using MinGW suite (Code::Block, DevC++, etc), you can try to find option where you can manually add compiler flags, and add **-lws2_32** into on of your compiler flag

---

Edit : Based on your comment above, so you're using Dev-C++ IDE, below is guide how you can use ws2_32.lib library inside your IDE

1. Go to top menu `Tools`, and click `Compiler Options...`

   [image]
2. Inside `Compiler Options`, tick checkbox `Add the following commands when calling the compiler`
3. Put compiler flag **-lws2_32** below into the textarea

   [image]
4. Press **OK**

Try again to compile your source code. If nothing go wrong, your program should be compiled successfully.

Regards

Comment: @Nguyen Tan Dat, if my answer helped you, then you click `Accept` button to tick that this question have been answered :)